# Comparing 2D arrays of strings

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method which generates a 2D array of strings, then places them in a `ArrayList`. I am trying to write a method which take a new 2D array and check it against those already in the array for duplication. This is what I have so far, it should return `true` for a new solution but it returns `false` every time. The calling method prints the arrays out and I can see that they are not the same.

```
public static boolean tester(String[][] b, ArrayList<String[][]> s)
{
    if (s.size() == 1) return true;
    boolean n = true;
    int count;
    int size = b.length * b[0].length;

    for (int i = 0; n && i < s.size() -1; i ++)

    {   
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < s.get(i).length; j ++)
            for (int k = 0; k < s.get(i)[0].length; k ++)
                if (s.get(i)[j][k].equals(b[j][k])) count ++;
                    if (count == size) n = false;

    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: *"double arrays of strings"* its called a 2 dimensional array, or 2d array for short. The term `double` in programming is "reserved" for the type of `double`. Unrelated to your answer/question but I had to read a few of the sentence over to make sure I was understating it right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code can get *way* simpler by using [Arrays.deepEquals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])):

```
public static boolean nonDuplicate(ArrayList<String[][]> s, String[][] b){

    for(String[][] e : s){
        if(Arrays.deepEquals(e, b)) return false; //e and b are duplicates
    }

    return true;
}
```

Your code may be incorrect because you didn't use braces (`{}`) around your for loops. So when you wrote:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < s.get(i).length; j ++)
        for (int k = 0; k < s.get(i)[0].length; k ++)
            if (s.get(i)[j][k].equals(b[j][k])) count ++;
                if (count == size) n = false;
```

It was interpreted as:

```
      for (int j = 0; j < s.get(i).length; j ++){
        for (int k = 0; k < s.get(i)[0].length; k ++){
            if (s.get(i)[j][k].equals(b[j][k])) count ++;
        }
      }

      if (count == size) n = false;
```

Which was likely (?) not your intention judging by your indentation, though notably white space (including indentation) doesn't mean very much in java aside from separating tokens.

Comment: That solution with the deep.equals is still returning a false every time...I am starting to wonder if something strange isnt going on elsewhere in the code; however I am printing out each 2D array as it is added to the arraylist and I can see that they are not the same, so I am at a loss as to what it might be.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. It actually was a problem elsewhere in the program- the arraylist was getting entirely filled with references to the same d2d darrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code gets interpreted by the compiler:

```
for (int i = 0; n && i < s.size() -1; i ++)
{   
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < s.get(i).length; j ++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < s.get(i)[0].length; k ++) {           
            if (s.get(i)[j][k].equals(b[j][k])) count ++; 
        }
    }
    if (count == size) n = false;
}
```

Imho its best to **always** use `{` and `}` to clarify your intentions to the compiler/reader of your code.

I guess what you wanted is this:

```
for (int i = 0; n && i < s.size() -1; i ++)
{   
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < s.get(i).length; j ++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < s.get(i)[0].length; k ++) {           
            if (s.get(i)[j][k].equals(b[j][k])) {
                count ++; 
            }
            if (count == size) {
                n = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you could also write:

```
public static boolean tester(String[][] b, ArrayList<String[][]> s)
{ 
    // ..

    for (int i = 0; n && i < s.size() -1; i ++)  {   
        for (int j = 0; j < s.get(i).length; j ++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < s.get(i)[0].length; k ++) {   

                if (s.get(i)[j][k].equals(b[j][k]) == false) {
                    return true; 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If understand that write, won't it stop and return "false" as soon as it doesn't match any one of the 2D arrays that are in the arraylist? I need it to keep looking through the entire list.